# Passing an object from middleware to an express route

Tags: node.js, express

I'm looking for an elegant solution to send data from a middleware function to the subsequent routes.

I guess I can add a property to req, but it doesn't feel right. Is there a better way?

```
app.post('/', filter);

var filter = function (req, res, next) {
    req.something = {};
    next();
};
```

Comment: Why you don't consider it right? I think is a good way to do it, but probably is better to attach data to the "res" object. Express has even a property call "locals" (eg: res.locals.something = {}), in this way you avoid to overwrite accidentally other variables.

Comment: yes, my concern is that the properties I attach are not "visible" enough and might break someone else's logic. res.locals sounds a bit better.

Comment: [Have a look](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though you ask for attaching data to `req`, but You can attach the data to `res` object using `res.locals`:

```
app.post('/', filter);

var filter = function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.myVar = 'myVal'; // data attched to response
  res.locals.myOtherVar = 'myOtherVal';
    next();
};
```

and this data will only be available throughout the request lifetime. i.e for that single request(*so I think wont matter if you attach the data to res object in this case*)